# cups-daemon fails to upgrade

Tags: 20.04

When I try to perform `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get the following error,

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cups-daemon
```

Doing `sudo dpkg --configure -a` gives,

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-daemon:
 cups-daemon depends on libcups2 (= 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2); however:
  Version of libcups2:amd64 on system is 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1.

dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Apply all upgrades o your system, as the correct package version of `libcups2` is `libcups2 | 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2    | focal-updates    | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` which isn't the package on your system as you've not applied all security fixes etc.  Don't forget there are upgrades `apt upgrade` cannot install; which is why the command `apt full-upgrade` exists (just like `apt dist-upgrade` exist with `apt-get`)

Comment: Did you solve it?
I am facing the same issue:
Setting up cups-daemon (2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2) ...
It stuck on this message. I have deleted the directories like that:
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock Maybe it works for you.